# Macbook dirty cache, after domain DNS change

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, dns

I have two devices connected to the same WiFi connection. I have changed the DNS of one domain. When I enter to that domain from device A it works OK, but if I try to enter from device B it does not work.

Device B is a Mac, I try all the available commands to clean the cache;

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponderew
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

It still happening the same in the Macbook, although I'm not available to see the DNS change but in the other device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily try to change the DNS Servers on your Mac to use the [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [Open DNS](http://www.opendns.com/) to see if is a problem with the DNS of your provider.

Comment: recently I change my ISP, and I was using an old router DNS address thank you!